# How to change this code to normal function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrow-functions

Hello everyone can anyone help me to convert this code by using normal function without using the arrow function.Your kind help will help me alot to accomplish my project

```
const arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow");
const movieLists = document.querySelectorAll(".movie-list");

arrows.forEach((arrow, i) => {
   const itemNumber = 
   movieLists[i].querySelectorAll("img").length;
   let clickCounter = 0;
   arrow.addEventListener("click", () => {
   const ratio = Math.floor(window.innerWidth / 270);
   clickCounter++;
   if (itemNumber - (4 + clickCounter) + (4 - ratio) >= 0) {
     movieLists[i].style.transform = `translateX(${
     movieLists[i].computedStyleMap().get("transform") 
     [0].x.value - 300
     }px)`;
 } else {
   movieLists[i].style.transform = "translateX(0)";
   clickCounter = 0;
 }
});
```

Comment: There are arrow functions in js and you also have functions on an object called arrow :D this is confusing

Comment: What help you do need? There's no use of `this` in your code, so there shouldn't be any surprises when swapping out the syntax.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you go

```
const arrows = document.querySelectorAll(".arrow");
const movieLists = document.querySelectorAll(".movie-list");

arrows.forEach(function (arrow, i) {
   const itemNumber = 
   movieLists[i].querySelectorAll("img").length;
   let clickCounter = 0;
   arrow.addEventListener("click", function () {
   const ratio = Math.floor(window.innerWidth / 270);
   clickCounter++;
   if (itemNumber - (4 + clickCounter) + (4 - ratio) >= 0) {
     movieLists[i].style.transform = `translateX(${
     movieLists[i].computedStyleMap().get("transform") 
     [0].x.value - 300
     }px)`;
 } else {
   movieLists[i].style.transform = "translateX(0)";
   clickCounter = 0;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `(...)=>{}` to `function(...){}` any time.
Arrows functions are however supported in all browsers (except IE)